# Next router was not mounted - Nextjs 13.4

Tags: next.js13, clerk

I'm using nextjs with clerk and this is the basic code that caused the issue when I tried to hide the sidebar and header from the auth pages

```
'use client'
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import "ui/styles/global.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./contexts/authContext";
import Header from "./components/navigation/Header";
import Sidebar from "./components/navigation/SIdebar";
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const poppins = Poppins({
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const pathname: any = usePathname();
  const hideOnRoutes = ['/sign-in', '/sign-up'];
  const shouldHide = hideOnRoutes.includes(pathname);

  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <html lang="en">
          <body>
          <div className={poppins.className}>
            <div className="flex h-screen">
              {!shouldHide && <Sidebar />}
              <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                {!shouldHide && <Header />}
                <main className="overflow-auto flex-grow p-5">{children}</main>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}
```

I thought this error only happens when one tries to import userRouter() from next/router instead of next/mnavigation,but I am already importing from next/navigation, what could be the issue here?